# PHP Form: Show input If is Selected

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to build a PHP form where as if you select an option on a drop-down that would trigger a set of inputs to display in relation to that option.

Example: I have a drop-down that has three options: A, B, C

If A is selected a set of inputs that have to do with option A display underneath. But if B is selected a different set displays. So on.

How would I execute this?

Comment: Using javascript and optionally ajax.

Comment: AJAX would only be needed if you have to fetch data from another source than the current page :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite straightforward, adapt as needed to your own context (*if* you have to get options from somewhere else *then* you'll need some AJAX) :

http://jsfiddle.net/7aydzs8j/

```js
$(function() {
    $("select").on("change", function() {
        if($(this).val() === "") {
            $("[data-parent]").hide();
        } else {
            $("div[data-parent='" + $(this).val() + "']").show().siblings("[data-parent]").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
[data-parent] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<div data-parent="A">
    <input type="text" placeholder="additional info for A">
    <input type="text" placeholder="additional info for A">
    <input type="text" placeholder="additional info for A">
</div>
<div data-parent="B">
    <input type="text" placeholder="additional info for B">
    <input type="text" placeholder="additional info for B">
    <input type="text" placeholder="additional info for B">
</div>
<div data-parent="C">
    <input type="text" placeholder="additional info for C">
    <input type="text" placeholder="additional info for C">
    <input type="text" placeholder="additional info for C">
</div>
```

Comment: How could I get this to show multiple inputs for say option A when selected, not just one?

Comment: Héhé :) amended :) it was quite fun to do, and data-attributes are perfect for this kind of targetting

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with php Ajax call
see the example here
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp

Answer (score -1):

I'd use Jquery, really easy to do this.
Based on the options selected you can add classes to an element. 
So you could make 3 displays en make them invisible. 
But if A is selected display 1 for instance could get a css class where the visible option is on.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp <--- this should come in handy.